# Pass argument into another script and then return back computed value

Tags: python

I have two python script `test1` and `test2`. If I hit ctrl+B in sublime under `test1.py`, the expected output should be
`7770` and `8880`

**test1.py**

```
import subprocess
import test2


subprocess.call(["python", "test2.py","777"]) #subprocess.call compulsory
print(test2.b) #8880 from test2
```

**test2.py**

```
import sys

a = sys.argv[1]
a = a * 10
print(a) #7770

'''
after some calculation
'''

#now return some number back to test1.py
b = 8880
```

How would I selectively get `b` only back to test1?
Tried `from test2 import b`, it did not work. It attempt to bring in `a` too, that caused the problem.

**Log:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".....\test1.py", line 2, in <module>
      import test2
  File "......\test2.py", line 3, in <module>
      a = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: The test2 that you executed via `subprocess.call()` is *utterly unrelated* to the test2 that you imported.  If you want the imported version to actually work, you have to arrange for `sys.argv` to contain the parameter it expects.  If you want the subprocess version to actually work, you have to get it to print `b`, or otherwise store it in some way that will survive the end of the process.

Comment: import test2 used in test1 executes the offending code in test2 and causes your IndexError of sys.argv (if you check what is sys.argv due to that import you will find it is ... just a ["test1.py"])

Comment: perhaps try to explain better what you really try to do. As mentioned in my answer. above code doesn't really work, doesn't really make sense.

So I think we're missing your exact intentions.

Answer (score 0):

Executing test2.py as subpprocess and importing test2.py are two completely different things. They both will use their own memory and access / modify their own versions of b.

So what you try to describe in `test1.py` cannot be done this way.

You have to choose different ways:

Either you do not use subprocesses and work only with python imports
or you call `test2.py` and parse the output of `test2.py` (The output of print)

As I don't know what you really try to achieve this example might be off.

test1.py:

```
import subprocess
import test2

cmd = ["python", "test2.py", "777"]
print("CMD", cmd)
rslt = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) #subprocess.call compulsory
print("STDOUT=", repr(rslt.stdout))
value = int(rslt.stdout)
test2.b = value
print(test2.b) #8880 from test2
```

test2.py:

````
import sys

b = 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # do not execute if being imported
    a = sys.argv[1]
    a = a * 10
    # print(a) #7770  # do not print here just print b

    '''
    after some calculation
    '''

    #now return some number back to test1.py
    b = 8880
    print(b)
    ```
````